# Координатная сетка Google Maps Android

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps-api, map

[image: Пример1]

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно реализовать такую сис-му координатной сетки на андроиде?При этом желательно чтобы квадраты были больше,но числа меньше.Т.к при подробном увеличении мы видим такое...
[image: Пример2]

Пытался и через мозаичные наложения и через наземные наложения.
Но получается только сетку создать,а вот вывести координаты не могу.

```
    public void Grid() {
    //HLP сетка
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String mSettings = sharedPreferences.getString(MAP_GRID, "True");
    if ("True".equals(mSettings)) {
        hlp =  new DebugHelper();
    } else if ("False".equals(mSettings)) {

    }
}
```

Часть кода,которым создаю сетку из примера HLP сетки.